# libGL open driver: "undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_sensor_info", glxgears works fine

Tags: shared-libraries, qt-creator, amd-gpu

My configuration:

```
t@t:/$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I try to run QTCreator which works with libGL and it crashes with following errors:

```
t@t:/$LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose qtcreator 

(qtcreator:14537): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « adwaita »

(qtcreator:14537): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « adwaita »
libGL: pci id for fd 22: 1002:67ef, driver radeonsi
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_sensor_info)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/radeonsi_dri.so failed (/usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/../dri/radeonsi_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_sensor_info)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL: pci id for fd 22: 1002:67ef, driver radeonsi
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_sensor_info)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/radeonsi_dri.so failed (/usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/../dri/radeonsi_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_sensor_info)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_sensor_info)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/../dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_sensor_info)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current
QQuickWidget::resizeEvent() no OpenGL context
```

I run glxgears, it works (I see the wheels moving) and it shows which driver it uses:

```
t@t:/$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears -info
libGL: DRI3 is disabled, try running in DRI2 mode.
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/amdgpu_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
GL_RENDERER   = AMD Radeon (TM) RX 460 Graphics
GL_VERSION    = 4.5.13453 Compatibility Profile Context 16.40.5
GL_VENDOR     = ATI Technologies Inc.
```

I tried to make a symbolic link to make QTCreator uses the same library as glxgears:

```
t@t:/$ sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so.old
t@t:/$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
t@t:/$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose qtcreator 

(qtcreator:22657): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « adwaita »

(qtcreator:22657): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « adwaita »
libGL: pci id for fd 22: 1002:67ef, driver radeonsi
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Here are all my libGL.so files:

```
t@t:/$ find /usr -iname "*libGL.so*" -exec ls -l -- {} + 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 janv. 29 20:49 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 453128 janv. 29 20:50 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 janv. 29 21:07 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 févr.  6 06:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.renamed
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 janv. 13 09:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.renamed -> mesa/libGL.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 janv. 29 21:07 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 janv. 29 21:07 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 467520 janv. 29 21:08 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

So what should I do to make QTCreator using same libGL library than glxgears?

Answer (score -1):

Delete the symbolic links to avoid problems like segmentation problems and try to install this:

```
apt-get intall -y mesa-utils and libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Comment: Change intall by install in your answer
It does not solve the problem
I removed sym link and update libgl1-mesa-glx